# open option menu when the imageview was clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a custom toolbar which is contain two imageView to open custom navigation drawer and option menu. the problem is how can override onCreateOptionsMenu method to open option menu when the imageView is clicked.

Comment: Why are you overriding onCreateOptionsMenu() if you are using a custom toolbar? you can use onClick with the toolbar image.

Comment: @Aditya how I can use onClick to open option menu?.